# Testing SharedFlow in runTest fails with UncompletedCoroutinesError after hanging for 60 seconds

Tags: kotlin, testing, kotlin-coroutines

I have a class that performs some work and immediately returns a result inside a suspend function, but also contains a public SharedFlow to update other components about when this work happens (For instance, a class that performs a user login and then also provides a Flow to update listeners when a new user has logged in):

```
class ExampleClass(private val api: Api, externalScope: CoroutineScope) {
    private val _dataFlow = MutableSharedFlow<String>()
    val dataFlow = _dataFlow.shareIn(externalScope, SharingStarted.Lazily)

    suspend fun performLogin(): String {
        val result = api.getData()
        _dataFlow.emit(result)
        return result
    }
}

interface Api {
    suspend fun getData(): String
}
```

I've written a test for this class. The assertion in the test passes, but the test still fails after hanging for 60 seconds with `UncompletedCoroutinesError`:

```
class ExampleClassTest {
    private val mockApi = mockk<Api> { coEvery { getData() } returns "hello" }
    private val testScope = TestScope()

    @Test
    fun thisTestTimesOutAndFails() = testScope.runTest {
        val exampleClass = ExampleClass(mockApi, testScope)
        assertEquals("hello", exampleClass.performLogin())
    }
}
```

How do I get the test to pass?

Answer (score 4):

Even though replacing `testScope.runTest` with the top-level `runTest` can make the test pass, it's important to make sure there is only a single TestScope in your tests, or bad behavior could occur. To fix this with a single TestScope, we can pass its `backgroundScope` into the class under test:

```
    @Test
    fun thisTestPasses() = testScope.runTest(dispatchTimeoutMs = 1000) {
        val exampleClass = ExampleClass(mockApi, testScope.backgroundScope)
        assertEquals("hello", exampleClass.performLogin())
    }
```

`testScope.backgroundScope` will automatically be cancelled properly when the test finishes, and the test will no longer hang and fail UncompletedCoroutinesError.

Sources:

- https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/3157046/the-android-coroutine-testing-https-developer-android-com-ko
- https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-test-scope/background-scope.html
- https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test#creating-your-own-testscope